# How to solve the error of this select writing in oracle?

Tags: oracle

I want to do the select from the range 06/01/2019 to 09/01/2019, but the program returns other ranges, like show the image.

Remember that my date field in the database is varchar2, and I store it in the format dd / MM / yyyy

[image]

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: DON'T STORE DATES AS STRINGS! Just...don't. It never ends well.

Comment: Thanks @BobJarvis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding @user7294900's answer, as you're storing your 'date' value as a string, you have to convert both the column value and your target-range values from strings to actual dates.

If you do:

```
WHERE DATA_TRANSACAO BETWEEN '06/01/2019' AND '09/01/2019'
```

then you are doing string comparisons between the column value and those literals, and *as a string* anything starting with '07' or '08' (and most starting with '06') will be considered part of that range. Oracle is treating them purely as strings, it doesn't know or care that you have the notion of days and months, or that you consider the order to be something different.

If you're really stuck with strings then you need to compare both sides of the comparison to dates:

```
WHERE TO_DATE(DATA_TRANSACAO, 'DD/MM/YYYY') BETWEEN TO_DATE('06/01/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
  AND TO_DATE('09/01/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

or with ANSI literals:

```
WHERE TO_DATE(DATA_TRANSACAO, 'DD/MM/YYYY') BETWEEN DATE '2019-06-01' AND DATE '2019-01-09'
```

or (though this is more useful if there can be non-midnight times, which isn't the case in your data):

```
WHERE TO_DATE(DATA_TRANSACAO, 'DD/MM/YYYY') >= DATE '2019-06-01'
AND TO_DATE(DATA_TRANSACAO, 'DD/MM/YYYY') < DATE '2019-01-10' -- notice one day later
```

You should also be aware that having to convert the string value for *every row* in your data before you can compare it means that if you have a simple index on that column it cannot be used, and a full table scan will be done even for a tiny target date range. (You can add a function-based index to speed this up, but that's a sticking plaster approach.)

This kind of thing is [why you should be using the correct data type](https://asktom.oracle.com/Misc/see-you-just-cannot-make-this-stuff-up.html). There is also no need to store the date and time parts separately, and that makes other types of comparison and data extract harder and more complicated than it needs to be too.

I would really recommend that you revisit your data model and change from separate strings for `DATA_TRANSACAO` and `HORA_TRANSACAO` to a single `DATE` column which contains the whole date/time value as the proper data type. You'll then be able to use the simpler form, with no conversion of your table data, of something like (with a made-up combined column name):

```
WHERE DATAHORA_TRANSACAO >= DATE '2019-06-01'
AND DATAHORA_TRANSACAO < DATE '2019-01-10' -- notice one day later
```

Comment: Thank Alex Poole. This "WHERE TO_DATE(DATA_TRANSACAO, 'DD/MM/YYYY') BETWEEN TO_DATE('06/01/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
  AND TO_DATE('09/01/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY')" worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If you expect 06/08 values to represent days, be explicit:

```
BETWEEN TO_DATE('06/01/2019','DD/MM/YYYY')
AND TO_DATE('09/01/2019','DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Currently it return 06/08 values as months, In general when compare date column use [dates and not strings](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:2858890655722)

> I am strongly ENCOURAGING you to use to_date to avoid ambiguities (compare strings to strings, numbers to numbers, dates to dates -- don't RISK confusion comparing strings to numbers, dates to strings).

Comment: user7294900 thank you for your answer. But it is not working. Remember that my date field in the database is varchar2, and I store it in the format dd / MM / yyyy

Comment: @JoãoNzuzi don't do it, save as date, and it looks you save it as MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: Thanks for your advice @user7294900